# Installing javamelody 401 "Authentication Required"

Tags: tomcat, java-melody

A "getting started" with JavaMelody question. 
I have an existing tomcat web service I'd like to profile with javamelody.

I followed the [Step 1 in their instructions here](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#1-jar-files), redeployed the war.
 
My tomcat server is set up with https. My context is, say, "foo-service".  
So I then went to `https://<host>/foo-service/monitoring`, but was given the

"Error 401 Authentication Required".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed anything else e.g. your `conf/tomcat-users.xml` or is there an other chance you restricted to certain URLs in your tomcat?
Maybe some filter in your web.xml is catching your calls to the url before that. Best would be to post your web.xml.

Also have a look into the security chapter: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#16-security